# Enable and Disable the datepicker desired date after the selection condition true or false in select option

Tags: jquery

I want to disable the date in the datepicker on the basis of select condition.

I have a form in which there are two form inputs first one is drop down and second one is date picker in the drop down there are two condition 1st one is small and the second one is medium.

If the user select the small from the drop down then the date picker shows the date from the current date and if the user select the medium from the drop down then the date show +2 from the current date. Rest of the previous date are disabled and the upcoming dates are visible in the date picker.

Is it possible? if yes then please give us some idea for how to set the condition in the date picker function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the datepicker on the change event of select. For that use `setStartDate` option to update the datepicker.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#date').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    startDate: "today",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"
  });

});


$(document).on('change','.option',function(){
  $selectedVal = $(this).val();

  if($selectedVal == 'small'){
    $('#date').val('');
    $('#date').datepicker('setStartDate','today');
  }
  else{
    $('#date').val('');
    $('#date').datepicker('setStartDate','+2d');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="option">
  <option value="small">Small</option>
  <option value="medium">Medium</option>
 </select>
 
 <input type="text" id="date" >
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
The code is good for the small condition but when the user select the medium then the date will start from the 19th of june 17th and 18th will be disabled.

Comment: @RaviSingh : For the use ```setStartDate``` option to update the datepicker. Please run the snippet again

Comment: can you please add the code for exclude the weekends in the same code?

Comment: Hi @nishal-k-r please help me out.

Comment: @RaviSingh : You can add ```daysOfWeekDisabled```  option to datepicker to disable the days of the week. For more, you can check this [datepicker demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox) site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.The above code was resolved my issue.

Comment: @RaviSingh: Great to hear that. Then please upvote the comment if it is useful.